# how to create docker for development

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose

I create a docker compose and Dockerfile, and start my react application on 3000 port, but when I changed something in my code browser doesn't reload. And little small fact, when I change index.html in public dir, my browser reload.

I'm using typescript maybe it causes problem?

*docker-compose.dev.yml*

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  react:
    build:
      context: ./client
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    container_name: react
    volumes:
      - "./client:/usr/app/cx"
      - "/usr/app/cx/node_modules"
```

*DockerFile*

```sh
FROM node:16.13.1
    
WORKDIR /usr/app/cx
    
COPY package*.json ./
# COPY tsconfig.json ./
    
RUN npm install --silent
       
EXPOSE 3000
    
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: What does the CMD `npm start`? Do you use `tsc`?

Comment: command start my dev server. webpack maybe use tsc, i dont know, it hidden

Comment: You're using react if I understood correctly. Shouldn't you have `stdin_open: true` `tty: true` in your react service to keep your server running? What is your operating system?

Comment: @SamiElk its not help.

Comment: i searched all SO, github and other resources, but not event one solution not help me